# Meaning of 修养­­­­

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The [dictionary](http://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E4%BF%AE%E5%85%BB) defines 修养 as:

> accomplishment / training / self-cultivation

However many examples in context seem to have the sense of the development of being a gentleman / lady, or being cultured.

I would like to know what kind of personal development 修养 implies. In western bookshops, for example, there is often a "self help" section. Is this 修养? What about religious practice?

Comment: 素质 and 修养 are always used together. "一个高素质高修养的人" is a gentleman that's kind and educated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Baidu Baike:](http://baike.baidu.com/view/54173.htm)

> 指人的行为和涵养，与人的性格、心理、道德、文化等有着紧密的联系，即为人综合素质的表现。

Simple Translation:

修养 refers to a person's behavior and conservation, which is closely linked with his personality, psychological state, moral view, cultural knowledge and things. It is the overall quality of a person.

So it is a big word. It can refer to how much a person knows in a particular area, or how a person treat the others, or many things else.

Comment: I agree. I think it has some of the nuances of 'breeding'. I also suspect the term has Confucian overtones -- it sounds like the thinking of Zhu Xi and people of that era, who talked of things like moral cultivation.

Comment: @Bathrobe Yeah~ The Baidu Baike page includes a paragraph from Cheng Yi's works. Cheng Yi and Zhu Xi are usually mentioned together.